# What is the relation between the matrices corresponding to a linear transformation...?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T:V\mapsto W$ be a linear transformation, where $dimV=n$ and $dimW=m$.

We know that, if $n=m$, then the matrices corresponding to the linear transformation $T$ are SIMILAR.

My question is, what will happen when $m$ and $n$ are unequal...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a change of basis $(n,n)$-matrix $P$ for the vector space $V$, and a change of basis $(m,m)$-matrix $Q$ for the vectorspace $W$, such that the matrices for $T$: $A$ in the ‘old’ bases and $A'$ in the ‘new’ bases respectively, are linked through the relation:
$$A'=Q^{-1}AP$$
Such matrices are said to be *equivalent*.

Comment: You mean, here 'Similar' is replaced by 'equivalent'....? It is clear that two similar matrices are equivalent.

Comment: Yes. ‘Equivalent’ is more general than ‘similar’.